# how to read JSON data from the api with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

[image: results after]Hello I'm trying to read JSON data from an api but it doesn't work when I try to get data from that api works fine and when I try to get the distance value I get undefined.Please help

The code

```
fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=meter&origins=Gurd%20Shola%201%20Station,%20Addis%20Ababa&destinations=Bole%20Medhane%20Alem%20Church,%20Addis%20Ababa&key=API_KEY')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
// Work with JSON data here
console.log(data.rows.elements.distance.value)
 })
  .catch(err => {

 })
```

the result from the web is just like this

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Addis Ababa, Ethiopia" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Addis Ababa, Ethiopia" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "6.4 km",
                  "value" : 6386
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 mins",
                  "value" : 901
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Rows property is an array of objects so try to use loop and access the property.

Comment: that's because 'elements' is an array and to fetch any particular value you need to access it using data.rows[0].elementes[0].distance.value or run a loop to access every value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `data.rows.elementes.distance.value` to `data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value`..

Check for typo here it is `elements` and **not** `elementes`..

Also `rows` and `elements` is an array and if you need to get the distance then you need to get it like `rows[0].elements[0].distance` ..

```js
const data = {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Addis Ababa, Ethiopia" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Addis Ababa, Ethiopia" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "6.4 km",
                  "value" : 6386
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 mins",
                  "value" : 901
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}

console.log(data.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
```

Comment: Typos, they're inevitable.

Comment: @haptomee, try like ```console.log(data.rows[0].elements[0].distance);```..

Comment: @haptomee, As rows is also array you need to put ```rows[0]``` as well.. Updated the answer..